# Parsing LocalDate and list of nested objects in ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, list

Can anyone help me please .
I am trying to get solution to two problems. First, how to display LocalDate in ajax response. 2nd, iterating over list of Custom objects received in ajax response.

I am passing List of Custom Object and localDate in ajax response and not sure how to display it in UI. date filed is displaying [object object]. Below is my ajax call code.

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        'sDom' : 'T<"clear">lrtip',
        "sort": "position",
        "sAjaxSource": "springPaginationDataTables.web",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "name" },
            { "mData": "position" },
            { "mData": "office" },
            { "mData": "phone" },
            { "mData": "start_date" },
            { "mData": "salary" },
            { "mData": "dob" },//LocalDate
            { "mData": "addresses" },//list of addresses

        ],
        columnDefs: [
                     {
                         targets: [ 6 ],
                         render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                             console.log(type);
                             return data;//process LocalDate here
                         }
                     },
                     {targets: [ 7 ],
                         render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                             console.log(type);
                             return data;//process addresses list here
                         }

                     }
                    ]
    } );
```

From MVC Controller I am passing list Of persons into JSON object as below

```
PersonJsonObject personJsonObject = new PersonJsonObject();
        //Set Total display record
        personJsonObject.setiTotalDisplayRecords(500);
        //Set Total record
        personJsonObject.setiTotalRecords(500);
        personJsonObject.setAaData(personsList);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String json2 = gson.toJson(personJsonObject);

        return json2;
```

PersonJsonObject  is Jquery Datatable kind of object which holds records track and list of data to be displayed on UI.
Person object has list of address Object. How do iterate over list after getting list say data.getaddresses and store this in variable. I know how do we iterate over list using jsp tags but not sure how to do same in Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved. For LocalDate issue, custom Module needs to be registered. Check this link for details.
[Ajax response does not parse LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445035/ajax-response-does-not-parse-localdate)

For iterating over list, use simple jquery foreach loop

```
$j.each(data, function (index, value) {
        var temp = value.field1+" "+value.field1+" ";//field1 and field2 are fields of custom object
        console.log(temp);
   return temp;
  });
```