# Ajax response does not parse LocalDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, localdate

I need to pass Localdate as part of the Ajax response to jquery datatables. LocalDate field does not display its value. Instead it prints [object,Object]. Obviously, it means LocalDate was not deserialized. Can some one please explain how to deserialize Localdate to display it properly.
Below is my Jquery Code:

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
            "bProcessing" : true,
            "bServerSide" : true,
"sAjaxSource" : "jsonSource.web",
            "aoColumns" : [
            {
                "mData" : "name"
            }, {
                "mData" : "position"
            }, {
                "mData" : "office"
            }, {
                "mData" : "phone"
            }, {
                "mData" : "salary"
            }, {
                "mData" : "dob"
            }
            ],
            columnDefs : [ {
                targets : [ 5 ],
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
                    var date = JSON.parse(json);
                    console.log("json: " + json + "date : " + row);
                    return data;
                }
            }
            } ]
            });
```

Server Side  code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/springPaginationDataTables.web", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String springPaginationDataTables(HttpServletRequest  request) throws IOException {

        //Fetch search parameter
        String searchParameter = request.getParameter("sSearch");
        final String sortColumn = request.getParameter("iSortCol_0");
        final String sortOrder = request.getParameter("sSortDir_0");
        //Fetch Page display length
        Integer pageDisplayLength = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("iDisplayLength"));
        //Fetch the page number from client
        Integer pageNumber = 0;
        if (null != request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"))
            pageNumber = (Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"))/pageDisplayLength)+1;      
        System.out.println("sSearch : "+searchParameter);
        System.out.println("pageDisplayLength : "+pageDisplayLength);
        System.out.println("pageNumber : "+pageNumber);
        System.out.println("iSortCol_0 : "+sortColumn);
        System.out.println("sSortDir_0 : "+sortOrder);

        List<Person> personsList = new ArrayList<Person>();
                Person person2 = new Person();
                person2.setName("John Landy");
                person2.setPosition("System Architect");
                person2.setSalary("$320,800");
                person2.setOffice("NY");
                person2.setPhone("999999999");
                person2.setStart_date("05/05/2010");
                person2.setDob(LocalDate.parse("1989-07-09"));
personsList.add(person2);
//apply server side search
//apply server side sort
//BuildDataTable object             
        PersonJsonObject personJsonObject = new PersonJsonObject();
        //Set Total display record
        personJsonObject.setiTotalDisplayRecords(500);
        //Set Total record
        personJsonObject.setiTotalRecords(500);
        personJsonObject.setAaData(personsList);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String json2 = gson.toJson(personJsonObject);

        return json2;
        }
```

Comment: _"Obviously, it means LocalDate was not deserialized."_ - Not quite sure you can draw that conclusion yet. It could be that the object was nested inside an initial object. In this case it was deserialized but referencing it in the JavaScript as an object would provide you with the same result. What does `console.log(data);` return in your `render: function() ...` function?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. It prints [object, Object]
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
      var date = JSON.parse(json);
console.log("json: " + json + "date : " + data);

Output:
     json: {"year":1989,"month":1,"day":10}date : [object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. had to extend SimpleModule from codehaus to implement serialisation/deserialisation for LocalDate. Below is my code:

```
public class LocalDateSimpleModule extends SimpleModule{

    public LocalDateSimpleModule(String name, Version version) {
        super(name, version);
        addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new JsonSerializer<LocalDate>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                ToStringSerializer.instance.serialize(value, jgen, provider);
            }
        });
        addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                ToStringSerializer.instance.serialize(value, jgen, provider);
            }
        });
        addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDate>() {
            @Override
            public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                return LocalDate.parse(jp.getText());
            }
        });
        addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>() {
            @Override
            public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                return LocalDateTime.parse(jp.getText());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Register this module in servlet-springs.xml

```
<bean id="objectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"/>

<bean name="localDateModule" class="packge.LocalDateSimpleModule">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="LocalDateModule" />
    <constructor-arg name="version" ref="version" />
</bean>
<bean name ="version" class="org.codehaus.jackson.Version">
    <constructor-arg value="1"/>//some value
    <constructor-arg value="1"/>
    <constructor-arg value="1"/>
    <constructor-arg value=" "/>
</bean>
```